# Django context processor constants work in dev but not in production

Tags: django, django-templates, wsgi

I have a context processor which makes constants available in templates, including base template.

On my vagrant development server, using runserver, these work fine. The production server uses apache and WSGI.

I'm using Django 1.9.4 on both development and production.

This is the context_processors.py

```
from .constants import *


def template_constants(request):
    return {'collection_name': COLLECTION_NAME,
            'website_name': WEBSITE_NAME,}
```

This is from settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                 'django.template.context_processors.request',
                 'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                 'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                 'django.template.context_processors.media',
                 'django.template.context_processors.static',
                 'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                 'myapp.photos.context_processors.template_constants',
             ],
         },
     },
 ]
```

Constants are just in a file constants.py in my app, which I import into files which use them. The file has lines such as:

```
WEBSITE_NAME = "website name"
```

My views use render which should be including RequestContext

```
return render(request, 'page.html', template_variables)
```

I get no error messages, the variables simply don't have a value in the templates on production, so nothing is shown.

Apart from deployment, the code on production and dev is exactly the same.

Things I've tried:
- Adding string value directly into context_processors.py file (eliminating it being a potential issue importing variables from constants.py)
- Going back to Django 1.8 and 1.7 to check if it's something related to a specific version

None of these changes made any difference.

Comment: How are the constants set?

Comment: added to description now

Comment: Try adding `"debug": True` into `TEMPLATES['OPTIONS']` temporarily to see if that gonna output anything useful.

Comment: This seems to have now fixed itself and I'm not sure exactly how. I believe there was an issues with settings.pyc, either it was out of date or had the wrong permissions.